# Which Kotlin download do I need?

Tags: kotlin

I'm getting started with Kotlin, and on the [downloads page](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.3.72) I see two different possibilities that look relevant for me:

- kotlin-compiler
- kotlin-native-windows

What's the difference?  In what case would I need one or the other?

Comment: `kotlin-compiler` seems to work with all platforms. Most likely the `kotlin-compiler` is used to compile to some intermediary form that kotlin can understand and the native modules are used to translate that to machine code for specific platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you won't use CLI to compile, build and run Kotlin projects a lot. Well, maybe you'll need a standalone compiler a few times compiling "Hello world" when starting with this language. BTW, you can use https://try.kotlinlang.org to compile simple programs and play with the language without local installations.

But as you proceed, it won't be enough. Most Kotlin projects today use either [Gradle](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) or [Maven](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html). Gradle scripts [could be written in Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) themselves. I recommend you taking this extra step and use build tools instead of standalone compiler, as it will simplify a lot if things in future. IntelliJ IDEA, the most popular IDE for Kotlin made by JetBrains, the company behind Kotlin, allows you to create Gralde-based Kotlin projects in a few clicks.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin is a *multi-platform* language. It can be compiled to produce binaries compatible either with:

- Java
- JavaScript
- A native platform (Windows, Linux, iOS, etc.)

Which compiler you should choose depends on your needs. If you don't need to make your code operate with a C library or a specific OS tool, I'd recommend the *kotlin-compiler*, so you'll get an app executable through Java, which (at least for now) produce more optimized programs, and also easily portable (install a jre on target computer and you're ready to execute your Kotlin program). Plus, you'll be able to use any Java lib you need in your kotlin program.

*Note* : Official documentation contains guides to get started:

- [Command line compiler for JVM](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html)
- [Command line compiler for native executables](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/using-command-line-compiler.html)